# Action on associated graded algebra inducing action on filtered algebra

Tags: ring-theory, modules, hopf-algebras, graded-rings, filtrations

Suppose $Q$ is a filtered algebra, with associated graded algebra $\text{gr}(Q)$. If we have an action of a ring $R$ on $\text{gr}(Q)$ (i.e. $\text{gr}(Q)$ is an $R$-module) then it seems clear that, under a choice of isomorphism between $\text{gr}(Q)$ and $Q$, $Q$ will also be an $R$-module. (I am interested in situations when $Q$ is a PBW-type deformation of $\text{gr}(Q)$ so a natural choice of such an isomorphism exists).

However what if $\text{gr}(Q)$ is an $H$-module algebra, for a Hopf algebra $H$. So in addition to being an $H$-module (as above), we also have that the product of $\text{gr}(Q)$ is an $H$-module homomorphism. In particular we have: $h\rhd 1=\epsilon(h)1$ and $h\rhd (a\cdot b)=(h_1\rhd a)\cdot (h_2\rhd b)$. When will the $H$-module structure on $Q$ (coming from $\text{gr}(Q)$) also make $Q$ an $H$-module algebra?

I can't find anything in the literature about this so any references/advice would be great.

Comment: There is no reason for which an R-module structure on Gr(Q) to determine another on Q in any natural way. It should not seem clear.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Since the underlying spaces of $\text{gr}(Q)$ and $Q$ are isomorphic, I'm not sure why we can't simply use the action of $R$ on $\text{gr}(Q)$ to define an $R$-module structure on $Q$.

Comment: If $\phi:\text{gr}(Q)\rightarrow Q$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces, and $\rhd:H\otimes \text{gr}(Q)\rightarrow \text{gr}(Q)$ is the action of $H$ on $\text{gr}(Q)$, then $\rhd':=\phi\circ \rhd\circ (\text{id}_H\otimes \phi^{-1})$ is an action of $H$ on $Q$.

Comment: The vector spaces grQ and Q are isomorphic but not canonically so, so there is a choice involved.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I can edit my question to suppose such a choice has been made, if that helps?